# iphone application development home button

Tags: iphone

im new to iphone development.can somebody please tell me how can i putt home button to each view of my application. pressing home button user will be provided home screen.

Thanks

Comment: You can do it by adding uibutton to every view.

Comment: Provide us with more information. What is your navigation in your app? What is the home screen?

Comment: Yes put a home button in xib file or through code and assign it an IBAction, and this action method if you are using NavigationController, simply popToRootViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a home button in xib file or through code in every view and assign it an IBAction, and in this action method if your app is using NavigationController to switch between views, simply do that in button's IBAction method

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES]`

Comment: hi. my application is in tableview and i was trying to find any inbuild method for home button. there are some methods like refresh, cancel save but i cant find home button. plz help. i want to add home button through pragmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your project based on `tabBarController` ... your this idea of making same button on all view is not good ....